# factory injection in magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Trying to override `authenticate` method of `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement`. Here is the code:

```
namespace namespace\module\Model\Customer;

class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{
    private $customerFactory;
    private $validationResultsDataFactory;
    private $eventManager;
    private $storeManager;
    private $mathRandom;
    private $validator;
    private $addressRepository;
    private $customerMetadataService;
    protected $logger;
    private $encryptor;
    private $customerRegistry;
    private $configShare;
    protected $stringHelper;
    private $customerRepository;
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $transportBuilder;
    protected $dataProcessor;
    protected $registry;
    protected $customerViewHelper;
    protected $dateTime;
    protected $objectFactory;
    protected $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
    protected $customerModel;
    protected $authentication;
    private $emailNotification;
    private $eavValidator;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Random $mathRandom,
        Validator $validator,
        ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        PsrLogger $logger,
        Encryptor $encryptor,
        ConfigShare $configShare,
        StringHelper $stringHelper,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        Registry $registry,
        CustomerViewHelper $customerViewHelper,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        CustomerModel $customerModel,
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->validationResultsDataFactory = $validationResultsDataFactory;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->customerMetadataService = $customerMetadataService;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->configShare = $configShare;
        $this->stringHelper = $stringHelper;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customerViewHelper = $customerViewHelper;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
        parent::__construct($customerFactory,$eventManager,$storeManager, $mathRandom,$validator,$validationResultsDataFactory,
            $addressRepository,$customerMetadataService ,$customerRegistry,$logger,$encryptor,$configShare,$stringHelper,$customerRepository,
            $scopeConfig,$transportBuilder,$dataProcessor,$registry,$customerViewHelper,$dateTime,$customerModel,$objectFactory,$extensibleDataObjectConverter);
    }
```

But i am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to namespace\module\Model\Customer\AccountManagement::__construct() must be an instance of namespace\module\Model\Customer\CustomerFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy given.

I think the reason is its a factory class or private. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you try overwrite whole class instead of plugin?

Comment: I need to do something inside that function which cant be done using before or after or around.

Comment: Can you share your need?

Comment: Thats the not important here i guess. Right now its a curiosity too you can say. It has to work. It work for other controllers. But why not here.

Comment: You didn't specify full class name for CustomerFactory. It must be `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory` but ObjectManager looking for `namespace\module\Model\Customer\CustomerFactory` instead. Not sure about why it passes `Proxy` class instead but you definitely need to fix class name.

Comment: @YaroslavOnischenko see the updated question. Its still same.

Comment: @KingshukDeb, please provide di.xml code you are using to configure ObjectManager with new preference. Example from Answer below is working for me but I used own di.xml configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{
    /**
     * AccountManagement constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory                      $customerFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface                    $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface                   $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random                               $mathRandom
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator                   $validator
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface             $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface              $customerMetadataService
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry                     $customerRegistry
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                     $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface             $encryptor
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share                         $configShare
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils                        $stringHelper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface            $customerRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface           $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder            $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor            $dataProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry                                  $registry
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\View                                $customerViewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime                           $dateTime
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer                             $customerModel
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory                         $objectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter         $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder                                        $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param FilterBuilder                                                $filterBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator $validator,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterfaceFactory $validationResultsDataFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $configShare,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $stringHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $customerViewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $customerFactory,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $mathRandom,
            $validator,
            $validationResultsDataFactory,
            $addressRepository,
            $customerMetadataService,
            $customerRegistry,
            $logger,
            $encryptor,
            $configShare,
            $stringHelper,
            $customerRepository,
            $scopeConfig,
            $transportBuilder,
            $dataProcessor,
            $registry,
            $customerViewHelper,
            $dateTime,
            $customerModel,
            $objectFactory,
            $extensibleDataObjectConverter
        );

        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    }
}
```

You can use $this->customerFactory, for customer model.

Delete 'var/generation/*' and flush cache.

Comment: Check the updated question. Its still giving me same error.

Comment: Delete 'var/generation/*'

Comment: kudos !! It worked after deleting var/generation. But kindly tell me one thing.  How do you generate all the class paths like this `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory` for all those injection. Do you know all the names or you can generate it somehow. However it works and really thanks for that. Now i can check how the plugin can be implemented into it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please read namespace for php, it will help you. It's simple, when you used to it, it will be easy for you too. Don't worry, read more :)

Comment: Ok. Sure. I will try it.